# angular-oauth2-oidc : Enabling silent refresh results in triggering many number of calls to fetch the token after 10 minutes

Tags: angular-oauth2-oidc

Enabling silent refresh using angular-oauth2-oidc results in triggering of a series of calls to fetch the token after ten minutes. It is observed that more than 100 calls are triggered to fetch the new token. I have not set any timeout Factor value, all the settings are by default.  I have used this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh() in my code to enable the silent refresh. Please help me how can we stop so many calls. Ideally, I think there has to be only one call fetch the refresh token based on the time out factor value or once the token expires.

Comment: Could you help us reproduce your situation, provide the minimum amount of code to get this situation? I'm guessing it's something specific to your setup.

Comment: Have you found a solution on this?